# in_array displaying all values from array loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to check if the values in a foreach loop are in an array from a query. If each of the values are not in the query it is supposed to get placed into the no_email_entered array, but when I print out the array it prints out ALL of the values that are contained in $user->user_email when it should be only printing out the ones that are not contained in the $my_user_mails array. I tried a nested foreach as well and that didn't seem to work either. I'd appreciate a second eye on this.

```
<?php
    //Creates empty array for inserts
    $no_email_entered = array();
    //Make a loop for the emails
    foreach( $users_for_site as $user ) {
    //Check if each email is in $my_user_emails array, if not add it to the $no_email_entered array 
        if( ! in_array( $user->user_email, $my_user_emails ) ) {
            $no_email_entered[] = $user->user_email;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Printed results of $no_email_entered array gives me ALL the emails from $users_for_site, which is not correct.

Comment: Looks okay at a glance. It's hard to tell without seeing the contents of `$my_user_emails` and `$users_for_site`. Should be fairly easy to see what's happening by just adding a few print statements in the code.

Comment: You know you can use array_diff() for that? http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Please double check your `$my_user_emails` array, it needs to be just one dimensional array e.g. just `array('email@host1.com', 'email@host2.com', 'email@host3.com')` also note that for huge arrays in_array() can takes long time. It's better to perform `$my_user_emails = array_flip($my_user_emails)` and than check `if (isset($my_user_emails[$user->user_email]))`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois `array_diff` won't work because the array he's looping over contains objects, and he's comparing to an array of strings.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how his array looks like. He didn't provide anything.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I'm basing it on how he does the comparisons. He's using `$user->user_email`, so `$users_for_site` is clearly an array of objects.

Comment: Yes, they are objects both of them

Comment: @Yaroslav Can you explain a bit what you're doing with the `array_flip`? Also, What makes you think `$my_user_emails` is multidimensional?

Comment: @Alex Howell please provide a sample of `$users_for_site` and `$my_user_emails` arrays.

Comment: @thomas i'm wrong with `array_flip` in case of array of objects. But in case of array of strings it will speed up selection. Because checking by key is faster than `in_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array()` performs comparison for each element in `needle` so inside you will have comparison like `$object1 == $object2`. This will be true only if both objects will have same properties with same values **and** will be instance of the same Class.

```
class Car{}
class CarRed extends Car{}

$obj_car1 = new Car();
$obj_car1->wheels = 4;
$obj_car1->doors = 5;

$obj_car2 = new Car();
$obj_car2->wheels = 4;
$obj_car2->doors = 5;

$obj_car3 = new Car();
$obj_car3->wheels = 4;
$obj_car3->doors = 5;
$obj_car3->id = 1234;

$obj_redcar = new CarRed();
$obj_redcar->wheels = 4;
$obj_redcar->doors = 5; 

var_dump($obj_car1 == $obj_car2); // true

var_dump($obj_car1 == $obj_car3); // false

var_dump($obj_car1 == $obj_redcar); // false
```

So check if your objects inside both arrays is instances of the same class. If it is and problem still exists, please provide a sample of that arrays.